# Sorting Data Pulled from Another Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have two worksheets in a workbook I'm designing for teachers to use next year.

One worksheet is where they enter student information and testing data and one worksheet is a general student roster. There's a lot of columns of data on the student information (SI) sheet, while only a few pieces of general information are the roster.

As set up now, the roster sheet is automatically generated based on data entry into the SI. The cells in the roster table are just coded as `=Table13[@[Last Name]]` so it pulls the info over essentially in real-time.

-The teacher enters info on SI

-Info from SI auto-populates into a table on Roster.

I can filter without an issue on the roster sheet, but I can't do any sorting there and that's the problem. If I want to list the students alphabetically on the roster, I have to go into the SI sheet and alphabetize there.

Is there any way to work around this? The excel filter also prompts with "sort smallest to largest" rather than "A to Z", so I'm thinking it's reading these cells as numbers? Someone on another site suggested using a PivotTable, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: This seemingly works if I don't use a table on the roster spreadsheet. All I have to do is make sure I hide the blank cells in all of the columns. Gotta be an easier way, but this will do...

Comment: You just need a Worksheet_OnChange event macro that auto-populates and sorts the table on the Roster worksheet when sufficient data is edited into the SI worksheet. Sadly, you haven't provided enough information to begin suggesting any code.